# \c_job_name_tl and \c_sys_jobname_str

Tags: expl3

I am developping a package using expl3, and `\c_job_name_tl` is used. Following a remark of egreg

> As of September 2015, \c_job_name_tl should become \c_sys_jobname_str – egreg Sep 30 '15 at 9:55

However, I do not know what is the proper way to have a code that is robust as to whether the version of expl3 is prior or posterior to 2015 (though I can probably easily fix it myself in this particular case.)

Comment: Well, if you plan for future use `\c_sys_jobname_str` ... I don't see much advantage in order to support pre 2015 states...

Comment: The idea is to always use the “official” name, in this case `\c_sys_jobname_str` and recommend users of your package to have an up-to-date distribution: this can be enforced by requiring a particular version of `expl3` (or a later one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `expl3` is still being developed, the recommendation of the team is to require a minimum version and to support only this. For example, in `siunitx` I have

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}[2015/09/11]
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ProvidesExplPackage {siunitx} {2017/02/19} {2.7d}
  {A comprehensive (SI) units package}
\@ifpackagelater { expl3 } { 2015/09/11 }
  { }
  {
    \PackageError { siunitx } { Support~package~expl3~too~old }
      {
        You~need~to~update~your~installation~of~the~bundles~'l3kernel'~and~
        'l3packages'.\MessageBreak
        Loading~siunitx~will~abort!
      }
    \tex_endinput:D
  }
```

which will yield an error and bail out if the required support is not available.

If you really feel that you have to support older installations then you can use `\cs_if_exist:NF`:

```
\cs_if_exist:NF \c_job_name_tl
  { \cs_new_eq:NN \c_job_name_tl \c_sys_jobname_str }
```

Note that this is not generally supported: the team remove older code quite deliberately.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I indeed reached the exact same fix. 

@Hupfer The thing is that coauthors I am working with do mostly have pre-2015 versions installed on their computer, and it is a painful task to require all of them to update.

I will issue a warning as a temporary solution, and prepare the code for making it mandatory in some time. I did not know the command `\@ifpackagelater`, which certainly is the good way to do this.