# Is there any difference between \endinput and \tex_endinput:D?

Tags: expl3, package-writing

In a few of my packages there is a fast mode, which usually begins with `\if@...@fast` and contains some minimal version of the commands, then ends with `\endinput\fi`.

Since I am trying to re-write these packages with expl3, I just found out that there exist a `\tex_endinput:D`. In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358278) of Joseph Wright, he gives the following example:

```
\@ifpackagelater { expl3 } { 2015/09/11 }
  { }
  {
    \PackageError { siunitx } { Support~package~expl3~too~old }
      {
        You~need~to~update~your~installation~of~the~bundles~'l3kernel'~and~
        'l3packages'.\MessageBreak
        Loading~siunitx~will~abort!
      }
    \tex_endinput:D
  }
```

which seems to suggest that `\tex_endinput:D` is a little bit different with `\endinput` since `\endinput` only keeps to the end of the current line.

I would like to make use of something like `\tex_endinput:D`, but in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378150) Joseph Wright said that "*none should appear outside of the core team code*" about the `:D` specifier. Thus I am a little confused, which one should I use in an expl3-based package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `...:D` functions are reserved to the team, but this is a very special case and `\tex_endinput:D` is the same as the primitive `\endinput`.

The brace after `\tex_endinput:D` that seems to confuse you has already been scanned and removed during macro expansion. This action is implemented with the standard construction

```
\if<whatever>
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{text for true}%
{text for false}%
```

where `{text for true}{text for false}` are absorbed as arguments to either `\@firstoftwo` or to `\@secondoftwo`, so the braces are stripped off and just one of the two token lists is reinserted in the input stream.

The important thing is that nothing follows the `}` after `\tex_endinput:D` on the same line, because otherwise it would still be scanned.

For instance

```
\makeatletter
\iffalse
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{whatever}
{\endinput
}\foo
```

would stop with an error, but

```
\makeatletter
\iffalse
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{whatever}
{\endinput
}
\foo
```

wouldn't.